# Plurals "one" is not working - always used "other" resource

Tags: android, android-resources, plural

I want to use Android's `plurals` resource.

Most questions out there mentioned that "one" is working but the other quantities are not;
But I am encountering the opposite...

#### Strings.xml

```
<plurals name="imagepicker_multiselect_not_enough">
    <item quantity="one">You have to select %d more image</item>
    <item quantity="other">You have to select %d more images</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="imagepicker_multiselect_enough">
    <item quantity="one">You have selected %d image</item>
    <item quantity="other">You have selected %d images</item>
</plurals>
```

Note that I also tried `1 image` instead of `%d image`.

#### SomeFragment.java

```
        if (newCount < minimumMultiSelectCount) {
            tvMultiSelectMessage.setText(getContext().getResources().getQuantityString(
                    R.plurals.imagepicker_multiselect_not_enough,
                    minimumMultiSelectCount - newCount,
                    minimumMultiSelectCount - newCount));
        } else {
            tvMultiSelectMessage.setText(getContext().getResources().getQuantityString(
                    R.plurals.imagepicker_multiselect_enough, newCount, newCount));
        }
```

I am always getting "You have selected 1 images" or "You have to select 1 more images"...

I made sure that this is the only place `tvMultiSelectMessage` has been called.

I also tried clean and rebuild, uninstall and reinstall, no luck...

Any idea?!

#### UPDATE

Just now I tried to change `other` to `few`, and I got this Exception:

`Resources$NotFoundException: Plural resource ID #0x7f0c0001 quantity=1 item=other`

`quantity=1 item=other`
`quantity=1 item=other`.....
`quantity=1 item=other`!!!!

Should I already treat it as bug?

Comment: actually, your code is ok and you should get what you desire, I'm not sure why you are getting that, what I feel like there would be a very simple mistake you did that causes this behavior. kindly revise the code carefully and make sure you don't do any modifications after set, and about the values of your `minimumMultiSelectCount` and `newCount`

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat There is one way I can prove there is no stupid mistake... In my whole project there is only this string resource which has the word "You have to select"; it is correctly `1` but it still uses `images`. In other words, assume I have some stupid mistakes, how can that mistake generate the result `You have to select 1 more images`?

Comment: actually I even tried your code in a simple application and everything is working perfectly, I think you should debug at that line to see what is going one, something else, try to add a pretty new string fields and replace them in setting the TextView to test if you are getting the same result.

Comment: Muhammed is right, the code works on my end too. you can try debugging into the getQuantityString() method?

Comment: With the above code, I get **1 images** when I set my test device language as Chinese and **1 image** when I set my test device language as English. Hope that helps!

Comment: @I_A_Mok Guessed it! Thank you for your answer... This behavior does not make sense at all.... Mind posting an answer and let me accept it?

Comment: In my case it is because of app localization. if in your application use English as Locale, those code should works. otherwise possibly does not work.